# how can i fix use location error in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Navbar from "../componant/Navbar";
import Announcement from "../componant/Announcement";
import Products from "../componant/Products";
import Newsletter from "../componant/Newsletter";
import Footer from "../componant/Footer";
import { mobile } from "../responsive";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";
import { useState } from "react";

const Container = styled.div``;

const Title = styled.h1`
  margin: 20px;
`;

const FilterContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Filter = styled.div`
  margin: 20px;
  ${mobile({ width: "0px 20px", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" })}
`;

const FilterText = styled.span`
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: 20px;
  ${mobile({ marginRight: "0px" })}
`;

const Select = styled.select`
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  ${mobile({ margin: "10px 0px" })}
`;

const Option = styled.option``;

const ProductList = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const cat = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const [sort, setSort] = useState("newest");

  const handleFilters = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setFilters({ ...filters, [e.target.name]: value, });
  };

  return (
    {cat} Filter Products: Color white black red blue yellow green Size XS S M L XL Sort Products:
    <Select onChange={(e) => setSort(e.target.value)}> Newest Price (asc) Price (desc) 
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

Comment: Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
invariant
C:/Users/hp/packages/react-router/index.tsx:19
  16 | export type { Location, Path, To, NavigationType };
  17 | 
  18 | function invariant(cond: any, message: string): asserts cond {
> 19 |   if (!cond) throw new Error(message);
  20 | }
  21 | 
  22 | function warning(cond: any, message: string): void {
View compiled
useLocation
C:/Users/hp/packages/react-router/index.tsx:397
  394 |  * @see https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation
  395 |

Comment: Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
invariant
C:/Users/hp/packages/react-router/index.tsx:19
  16 | export type { Location, Path, To, NavigationType };
  17 | 
  18 | function invariant(cond: any, message: string): asserts cond {
> 19 |   if (!cond) throw new Error(message);
  20 | }

Answer (score 1):

The error `useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.` is caused by an invariant violation. The error message is clear enough, you've not rendered the `ProductList` component using the `useLocation` hook ***within*** a routing context provided by a `Router`.

This is `react-router-dom` version 6

[useLocation](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/f16c5490dfa75f15dcfb86d2a981a7c58a9d1a33/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L395-L404)

> ```
> export function useLocation(): Location {
>   invariant(
>     useInRouterContext(),
>     // TODO: This error is probably because they somehow have 2 versions of the
>     // router loaded. We can help them understand how to avoid that.
>     `useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`
>   );
>
>   return React.useContext(LocationContext).location;
> }
> ```

You should have a single router wrapping your `App` component to provide a routing context to the entire app, which would including this `ProductList` component.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Based on some comments of yours from the other answer it appears you are mixing up the RRDv5 and RRDv6 components. V6 has no `Switch` component, it was replaced by a `Routes` component.

Check the installed version of `react-router` and `react-router-dom`:

```
npm run list react-router react-router-dom
```

If you have v5 installed, follow the [v5 docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start), otherwise if you've v6 installed, see the [v6 docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6). The [upgrading from v5 migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) will detail the differences between the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your app in `Routes` component.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";


const AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <App />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppWrapper;
```

Comment: i have try this but it didnt work

Comment: @GaethOmari what did you try? Provide please the code you tried

Comment: import Product from "./pages/Product";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import ProductList from "./pages/ProductList";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Cart from "./pages/Cart"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";3.

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

Comment: const App = () => {
  const user = true
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch > 
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
    <Route path="/products/:category">
          <ProductList />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/product/:id">
          <Product />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/cart">
          <Cart />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">{user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Login />}</Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          {user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Register />}
        </Route>
      </Switch>

Comment: </Router>
  );
};

export default App;

Comment: you didn't wrap it by `Routes`